# issue with interface io.javabrains.repository.DepartmentRepository

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I was trying to build CRM for university.But when I tried to auto built table within the hibernate,it displays me the following error:
Not managed type interface io.javabrains.repository.DepartmentRepository

I just tried to add Repository annotation to every other Repo classes but no results were achieved

Department Category.class

```
package io.javabrains.Entities;

import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;


@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude="Student")
@Entity
@Table(name="department")
public class DepartmentCategory {



    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public DepartmentCategory(int id, String name, Set<Student> students) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.students = students;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<Student> getStudents() {
        return students;
    }

    public void setStudents(Set<Student> students) {
        this.students = students;
    }

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "departmentCategory",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Student>students;



}
```

DepartmentRepository.class

```
package io.javabrains.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
@Repository
public interface DepartmentRepository extends JpaRepository<DepartmentRepository, Integer> {



}




CrmSchoolApplicaton.class

package io.javabrains;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@SpringBootApplication
public class CrmSchoolApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CrmSchoolApplication.class, args);
    }






}
```

...............

Answer (score 2):

try to change your JpaRepository :

```
public interface DepartmentRepository extends JpaRepository<Department, Integer>
```

instead of

```
public interface DepartmentRepository extends JpaRepository<DepartmentRepository, Integer>
```